# Check if azure VM compute Quota is available for a VM size via powershell

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, quota

I am looking to see if there is a way to check my current azure quota based on input of a VM size? (NOT a VM family)

Sample input:

```
Standard_D1
```

Sample output:

```
Standard DDSv4 Family vCPUs: You have used X/Y available quota
```

Comment: You can use the rest api : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/usage/list to get, for the specified location, the current compute resource usage information as well as the limits for compute resources under the subscription

Comment: @MantyQuestions Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get to doing that is through the [Usage - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/usage/list) API that @Jim mentioned above. The same is exposed via the [Get-AzVMUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmusage?view=azps-5.7.0) PS cmdlet as well. Note that this cmdlet can only accept a `Location` parameter and not a VM Size as such.

```
Get-AzVMUsage -Location "West US 2"
```

However, if there is a hard requirement for you to fetch the quota for the size you provide, you could combine it with `Get-AzComputeResourceSku` as follows:

```
$Location = 'West US 2'
$VMSize = 'Standard_D4d_v4'

# Get the list of VM SKUs for the given location
$SKU = Get-AzComputeResourceSku -Location $Location | where ResourceType -eq "virtualMachines" | select Name,Family

# Figure out the VM Family for the provided size
$VMFamily = ($SKU | where Name -eq $VMSize | select -Property Family).Family

# Fetch the usage
$Usage = Get-AzVMUsage -Location $Location | Where-Object { $_.Name.Value -eq $VMFamily }

Write-Output "$($Usage.Name.LocalizedValue): You have consumed $($Usage.CurrentValue)/$($Usage.Limit) available quota"

# Sample Output
# Standard DDv4 Family vCPUs: You have consumed 16/100 available quota
```

Also take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quotas) article for more information about vCPU quotas.